# DataTrigger to switch between different Lights in WPF Viewport3D - How to do it?

Tags: wpf, data-binding, datatrigger

I have a `Viewport3D` in which I want to alternate between two ligting conditions. Each light condition will be a `Model3DGroup` containing one or more Lights (`DirectionalLight`, `AmbientLight`, etc.).

I plan to use `DataTrigger`, but I'm not figuring out which object and which properties I should use, since `Model3DGroup` and its immediate parent (`ModelVisual3D`) don't have a `Style` property. If I use `Style` in the `Viewport3D` itself, with a `Setter.TargetName` property, the target is not recognized, as in the code below:

```
<CheckBox x:Name="shadows" Content="Shadows" />
<Viewport3D>
    <Viewport3D.Resources>
        <Model3DCollection x:Key="shaded_light">
            <DirectionalLight Color="White" Direction="-1,-1, -10" />
        </Model3DCollection>
        <Model3DCollection x:Key="solid_light">
            <AmbientLight  Color="White" />
        </Model3DCollection>
    </Viewport3D.Resources>
    <Viewport3D.Style>
        <Style>
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ElementName=shadows, Path=IsChecked}" Value="True">
                    <!-- The setter below doesn't work: "The name 'lightsource' is not recognized" -->
                    <Setter TargetName="lightsource" Property="Content" Value="{StaticResource shaded_light}"/>
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </Viewport3D.Style>
    <Viewport3D.Camera>
        <OrthographicCamera LookDirection="0,0,-1" Position="0,0,500" UpDirection="0,1,0" Width="400"/>
    </Viewport3D.Camera>
    <ModelVisual3D x:Name="lightsource">
        <ModelVisual3D.Content>
            <Model3DGroup Children="{StaticResource solid_light}" />
        </ModelVisual3D.Content>
    </ModelVisual3D>
    (...)
```

Comment: You forgot `<Style TargetType="Viewport3D">`

Comment: @Baboon Thanks, I corrected it. (But it still seems not to be the cause of the problem).

Comment: Can't style the `Children` property of `Viewport3D`, and `ModelVisual3D` cannot be styled at all.. out of luck I guess. You need to make a `ContentControl` and style it, putting a `Viewport3D` for each scenario..

Comment: Thank you for your kind interest. Right now "giving up" and trying some code-behind, I'll post some feedback if successful. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

Due to some limitations of `ViewPort3D` (has a `Style` property but not a `Template` one), I had to resort to code-behind in order to switch between different light sources. I'll post the relevant parts below, (with the variable names in portuguese this time):

(Note: I still would prefer XAML only solution with Binding, but I can't figure it out by now. If anyone post some XAML only answer, I'll be glad to accept it.)

Viewport:

```
<Viewport3D x:Name="viewport">
    <Viewport3D.Resources>
        <Model3DGroup x:Key="luz_sombreada">
            <DirectionalLight  Color="White" Direction="-1,-1, -10" />
        </Model3DGroup>
        <Model3DGroup x:Key="luz_cheia">
            <AmbientLight  Color="White" />
        </Model3DGroup>
    </Viewport3D.Resources>
    <ModelVisual3D x:Name="luzes" Content="{StaticResource luz_cheia}" />
```

CheckBox:

```
<CheckBox Content="Sombreado" Checked="sombreado_Changed" Unchecked="sombreado_Changed" />
```

Event handler in code-behind:

```
    private void sombreado_Changed(object sender, System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs e) {
        var nova_luz = new Model3DGroup();
        if (e.RoutedEvent.Name == "Checked") {
            nova_luz = (Model3DGroup)viewport.Resources["luz_sombreada"];
        }
        else if (e.RoutedEvent.Name == "Unchecked") {
            nova_luz = (Model3DGroup)viewport.Resources["luz_cheia"];
        }
        luzes.Content = nova_luz;
    }
```